# MySQL equivalent code for this Oracle trigger

Tags: mysql, oracle, database-trigger

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER  "BI_QUIZQUES" 
  before insert on "QUIZQUES"               
  for each row  
begin   
    :NEW.QID := "QUIZQUES_SEQ".nextval; 
end; 

/
ALTER TRIGGER  "BI_QUIZQUES" ENABLE
/
```

Comment: Could you expand a bit on what your question is? What have you tried? What is going wrong? Are you getting an error, and if so, what error? etc..

Answer (score 1):

The trigger does just the same as an autoincrement in mysql, so add autoincrement to the QID field in your table definition.

QID  is probably a primary key in your table.

```
create table QUIZQUES (
QID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
...
)
```